# Combining predicates in a functional way and allowing short-circuiting to work

Tags: c++, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting, boost-hana

### Foreword

I asked [a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259413/combining-predicates-in-a-functional-way) question: say I have a predicate `auto p1 = [](int x){ return x > 2; }` and a predicate `auto p2 = [](int x){ return x < 6; }`, how do I combine `p1` and `p2` to obtain `p1and2` such that `p1and2(x) == p1(x) && p2(x)`? The answer was *use [`boost::hana::demux`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga3a8316acd5efa22c3d1861b62d5df3c2)* (refer to the linked question for details).

### The new problem and the question

Sometimes, however, the evaluation of one predicate should occur only if the other predicate evaluates to a given truthness value, e.g. `true`.

For instance one predicate might be

```cpp
constexpr auto has_value = [](std::optional<int> opt){ return opt.has_value(); };
```

and the other predicate

```cpp
constexpr auto has_positive = [](std::optional<int> opt){ return opt.value() == 3; };
```

It's easy to recognize the following

```cpp
bool b1 = has_value(some_opt_int) && has_positive(some_opt_int); // true or false, but just fine either way
bool b2 = has_positive(some_opt_int) && has_value(some_opt_int); // runtime error if !some_opt_int.has_value()
```

Defining

```cpp
constexpr auto all = boost::hana::demux([](auto const&... x) { return (x && ...); });
```

and using it like so

```cpp
std::optional<int> empty{};
contexpr auto has_value_which_is_positive = all(has_value, has_positive);
bool result = has_value_which_is_positive(empty);
```

would lead to failure at run time, because [the it's the function call to the variadic generic lambda wrapped in `all` which forces the evaluation of its arguments, not the fold expression `(x && ...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048635/5825294).

So my question is, how do I combine `has_value` and `has_positive` to get `has_value_which_is_positive`? More in general, how do I "and" together several predicates such that they're evaluated only as much as the short-circuit mechanism requires?

### My attempt

I think that, in order to prevent the predicates from being evaluated, I can have wrap them in some function objects which, when applied to the argument (the `std::optional`), give back another object which wraps the predicate and the `std::optional` together, and has an `operator bool` conversion function which would be triggered only when the fold expression is evaluated.

This is my attempt, which is miserably undefined behavior because the assertion in `main` sometimes fails and sometimes doesn't:

```
#include <optional>

#include <boost/hana/functional/demux.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/curry.hpp>

template<typename P, typename T>
struct LazilyAppliedPred {
    LazilyAppliedPred(P const& p, T const& t)
        : p(p)
        , t(t)
    {}
    P const& p;
    T const& t;
    operator bool() const {
        return p(t);
    }
};

constexpr auto lazily_applied_pred = [](auto const& p, auto const& t) {
    return LazilyAppliedPred(p,t);
};

auto constexpr lazily_applied_pred_curried = boost::hana::curry<2>(lazily_applied_pred);

constexpr auto all_true = [](auto const&... x) { return (x && ...); };

constexpr auto all = boost::hana::demux(all_true);

constexpr auto has_value = [](std::optional<int> o){
    return o.has_value();
};
constexpr auto has_positive = [](std::optional<int> o){
    assert(o.has_value());
    return o.value() > 0;
};

int main() {
    assert(all(lazily_applied_pred_curried(has_value),
               lazily_applied_pred_curried(has_positive))(std::optional<int>{2}));
}
```

([Follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127093/short-circuiting-in-fold-expressions).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just realized that an ad-hoc lambda to do what I described is actually very terse:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <optional>

constexpr auto all = [](auto const& ... predicates){
    return [&predicates...](auto const& x){
        return (predicates(x) && ...);
    };
};

constexpr auto has_value = [](std::optional<int> o){
    return o.has_value();
};
constexpr auto has_positive = [](std::optional<int> o){
    assert(o.has_value());
    return o.value() > 0;
};

int main() {
    assert(all(has_value, has_positive)(std::optional<int>{2}));
    assert(!all(has_value, has_positive)(std::optional<int>{}));
}
```

However, [there's still something about short-circuiting in fold expressions that doesn't convince me...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127093/short-circuiting-in-fold-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is more subtle than what I can understand, but this quite simple solution seems to do the trick (as far as I can tell).

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template<typename Predicate1,
         typename Predicate2>
auto
lazy_and(Predicate1 p1,
         Predicate2 p2)
{
  return [&](const auto &arg)
  {
    return p1(arg)&&p2(arg);
  };
}

int
main()
{
  // basic predicates
  const auto has_value=[&](const auto &opt){ return opt.has_value(); };
  const auto is_positive=[&](const auto &opt){ return opt.value()>0; };
  // combination of predicates
  const auto has_value_and_is_positive=lazy_and(has_value, is_positive);
  const auto is_positive_and_has_value=lazy_and(is_positive, has_value);
  // test
  const auto test_predicate=
    [&](const auto &title, const auto &predicate, const auto &arg)
    {
      try
      {
        const auto result=predicate(arg);
        std::cout << title << " --> " << result << '\n';
      }
      catch(const std::exception &e)
      {
        std::cerr << title << " !!! " << e.what() << '\n';
      }
    };
  std::cout << "~~~~ empty ~~~~\n";
  const auto empty=std::optional<int>{};
  test_predicate("has_value",
                 has_value, empty);
  test_predicate("is_positive",
                 is_positive, empty);
  test_predicate("has_value_and_is_positive",
                 has_value_and_is_positive, empty);
  test_predicate("is_positive_and_has_value",
                 is_positive_and_has_value, empty);
  std::cout << "~~~~ positive ~~~~\n";
  const auto positive=std::optional<int>{5};
  test_predicate("has_value",
                 has_value, positive);
  test_predicate("is_positive",
                 is_positive, positive);
  test_predicate("has_value_and_is_positive",
                 has_value_and_is_positive, positive);
  test_predicate("is_positive_and_has_value",
                 is_positive_and_has_value, positive);
  std::cout << "~~~~ negative ~~~~\n";
  const auto negative=std::optional<int>{-3};
  test_predicate("has_value",
                 has_value, negative);
  test_predicate("is_positive",
                 is_positive, negative);
  test_predicate("has_value_and_is_positive",
                 has_value_and_is_positive, negative);
  test_predicate("is_positive_and_has_value",
                 is_positive_and_has_value, negative);
}

/**
~~~~ empty ~~~~
has_value --> 0
is_positive !!! bad optional access
has_value_and_is_positive --> 0
is_positive_and_has_value !!! bad optional access
~~~~ positive ~~~~
has_value --> 1
is_positive --> 1
has_value_and_is_positive --> 1
is_positive_and_has_value --> 1
~~~~ negative ~~~~
has_value --> 1
is_positive --> 0
has_value_and_is_positive --> 0
is_positive_and_has_value --> 0
**/
```